# How to load directive's template before jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS directive with custom templateUrl:

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/partials/templatel.html',
            replace: true,
            transclude: false

        };
    });
```

Now, the problem is that I'm also loading jQuery plugin that is trying to bind the elements in `template1.html`, but this template file is loaded after the plugin, so it fails. Is there a way I can defer plugin loading after this template is loaded or what I should do in this case ?

Comment: Initialize plugin in link function.

Comment: How do you mean initialize ? Just to copy/paste the whole plugin into link function or ?

Comment: No, I mean initialize plugin in link function. Like this `element.myPlugin();`.

Comment: `I'm also loading jQuery plugin that is trying to bind the elements` jQuery plugin should not bind anything by its own. If it does then this is not plugin.

Comment: dfsq, you just solved my problem, thanks

Comment: It was easy :) Glad to help, anyway.